# Adding first opembmc user for the webui

Tags: openbmc

I built an image for a rasp pi (not from meta-evb/meta-evb-rasberrypi) and managed to get the webui/bmcweb working and displaying the login. The console service is also running.

In both cases, the root/0penBmc login does not work. Reading the docs, it seems I have to add a user through the user management.

From a shell after booting, how do I add a user from the shell that would have permissions to then use the webui to manage users?

I assume either there is a command, or some manual way of sending commands to the dbus to add them. I can't find any documentation how to get over this.

Can someone give me some shell command examples?

Comment: By default root/0penbmc should work. You should check journal log to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance you have set the flag to disable the root user from including it as part of user management

```
 --disable-root_user_mgmt
```

if yes, `root/0penBmc` will work only for serial console and not for others.
Just check the same through serial console, using ipmitool command

ipmitool user list 1  --> if you are seeing root user here, then it must work, if your user list is empty then the image is with
`--disable-root_user_mgmt` and hence works as expected for that flag.

D-Bus command to create the user

```
busctl call xyz.openbmc_project.User.Manager /xyz/openbmc_project/user xyz.openbmc_project.User.Manager CreateUser sassb <username> 4 {"ipmi","web","redfish","ssh"} "priv-admin" true
```